# How to sort the given python dictionary with a list as values, based on one of the elements in list?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, key-value-store

Here is the dictionary:

```
{'A': [2, 4.2], 
 'B': [4, 4.5],
 'C': [2, 3.3], 
 'D': [2, 3.5], }
```

Sorting criteria:

1. Sort based on the **1st(first) element** of list of VALUE.
2. If the 1st element is the **same** for two keys, the one with the **greater value of 2nd element** is chosen as the greater one.

The result should be:

B -- 4 --  4.50

A  -- 2 -- 4.20

D  -- 2 -- 3.50

C  -- 2 -- 3.30

Comment: Could you add what you tried so far? Also, please elaborate on 2. I don't think I got the criteria

Comment: Try using a lambda with the `.sort()` function.

Comment: And another sorted dictionary ..... why? They are insert-ordered since 3.7 - why sort them? Dicts are not supposed to be sorted.

Comment: ou might want to check [how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 0):

You may sort the dictionary using various methods but if your goal is to print it, you simply cannot because Dictionaries are unpredictable and the output is random, you might want to use Ordered Dictionaries and / or use the sort function to sort them.

So that we can help you better, please show us what you tried and the errors you face so that it’s easier for us to help you out.

Comment: Dictionaries are not unpredictable - they are insert ordered. The order you insert keys rules how they are outputted - this holds for any python 3.7+, some pythons 3.6+ due to implementation details.